# How can I remove all elements in a list with a certain property?

Tags: isabelle

I want to match and remove those elements in `l :: 'a list` that match the predicate `P :: ('a => bool)`

What is the best way to accomplish such a task? How can I find out about existing functions that might help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Story:** Use `find_consts`

**Long Story:**

*This a How-To to conquer such problems.*

In `Main`, there is `List.dropWhile`

```
List.dropWhile :: "('a => bool) => 'a list => 'a list"
```

However, it only removes from the beginning. This may not be the intended function.

```
value "List.dropWhile (λ x. x = ''c'') [''c'', ''c'', ''d'']"
"[''d'']"

value "List.dropWhile (λ x. x = ''c'') [''d'', ''c'', ''c'']"
"[''d'', ''c'', ''c'']"
```

**Manual Approach**

We can write a function ourselves which removes all occurrences

```
fun dropAll :: "('a => bool) => 'a list => 'a list" where
    "dropAll P [] = []"
  | "dropAll P (x # xs) = (if P x then dropAll P xs else x # (dropAll P xs))"
```

**Searching the Library**

However, this function is equivalent to filtering with `¬ P`

How can we find such library functions?

If we know the signature of what we want to do, we can use `find_consts`

```
find_consts "('a ⇒ bool) ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'a list"
```

It returns 3 functions from Main, with that signature: `List.dropWhile`, `List.filter`, `List.takeWhile`

Now, let's show that we don't need `dropAll` but can do the same with `filter`.

```
lemma "dropAll P l = filter (λ x. ¬ P x) l"
  apply(induction l)
  by simp_all
```

It is advisable not to implement things like `dropAll`yourself but rather use filter. Thus, all lemmata proven for `filter` are usable.

**Hints**

Hint: we can use the convenient list comprehension syntax to write e.g. filter expressions

```
lemma "filter (λ x. ¬ P x) l = [x ← l. ¬ P x]" by simp
```

Comment: `find_consts` should be the first step when searching for existing functions (most of the time you have a rather specific idea of the signature and/or possible names). This is a bit lost in your long exposition. How about moving the hint to `find_consts` to the very top?

Answer (score 1):

One way to find functions you expect to exist is the document [What's in Main](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2013/doc/main.pdf) from the Isabelle documentation. It gives a quick overview of the main types, functions and syntax provided by the theory `Main` of Isabelle/HOL.

If you look at the List section in ths document, you find the function `filter` which seems to have the correct type.